# cant remove windows 8.1 and replace with 7 or linux

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, kali-linux

first of all, i tried to remove windows 8.1 which was build-in my system and replace it with windows 7. but i got blue screen which mentioned i need to disable shadowing and caching in bios. but my bios didn't have advanced tab ( phoenix bios) to do so. i couldn't figure out a way to unlock that hidden tab. so i decided to totally replace windows with Kali Linux. i even used live USB and deleted all partitions of windows and then inserted Kali DVD. but it can go further when reaches the step of installing.  i tried Kali USB and Kali DVD both same issue and same step. what is the problem? is it the shadowing and caching in bios which cause the problem? or windows 8.1 doesn't let any other OS sit on hard disk? i really want to set Kali as my OS ( i used it previously in VM) but i couldn't find any solution

Comment: I presume you mean "it _can't_ go further", but what do you mean by this? Does it appear to hang, or is there an error? If so, what error?

Comment: yes it was an error. the failing step is: installing the system

Comment: You still haven't explained the nature of the failure.

Comment: that is the error which been mentioned due to failure. longer one is : An installation step failed, you can try to run the failing item again from the menu or skip it and choose something else, the failing step is : Install the system. but when u go back and try again, u will get same error again. i believe its because of windows 8.1 and got something to do with shadowing/caching in bios

Comment: I am surprised that there is no more information than that. I have previously found that letting the installer choose partitions automatically can cause problems, so I select the option to set up partitioning myself during installation. My experience is with Ubuntu, but like Kali it is Debian-based, so I guess the installation process will not be too dissimilar.

Comment: i installed both graphical and non graphical. also i did both guided install and manual install. in all cases no chance. do u know how to unlock advanced thab in bios?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu in a Lenovo laptop, delivered with Win8 and running Phoenix BIOS with no Advanced tab, and it went in OK, though I did initially use Legacy Boot, which messed up Win8. I have since upgraded to 15.04 with UEFI boot (and also recovered Windows and upgraded to 10). Since you are not bothered about the Windows installation, you could try Legacy Boot with Kali; failing that, all I can suggest is to see if you can install Ubuntu, and if so then try to replace with Kali - all rather tedious, I know. (NB I have a scheduled power cut tomorrow, so I'll be off the air.)